# Where is FileZilla's info stored on Macbook on Yosemite

Tags: osx-elcapitan, filezilla

I need to transfer all my infos, ie. the online remote websites from the old OS to the new OS that I intend to install as a fresh El Capitan. How can I do it, ie. where is the data for FileZilla stored?

Comment: `$HOME/.filezilla`

Answer (score 0):

Try going to $HOME/.filezilla. If you can't then, try going to your logged in user and find it there in the folder subhierarchy.